# How to read a comment from xml request outside the root

Tags: xml, asp.net-web-api, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

What would be a good way to parse a comment in xml request on .net web api controller for the following example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Objects>
  <GUID-bf2401c0-ef5e-4d20-9d20-a2451a199362>
    <info job="SAVE" person="Joe" />    
    <info job="SAVE" person="Sally" />       
  </GUID-bf2401c0-ef5e-4d20-9d20-a2451a199362>
  <GUID-bf2401c0-ef5e-4d20-9d20-a583284112>
    <info job="SAVE" person="John" />    
    <info job="SAVE" person="Julie" />       
  </GUID-bf2401c0-ef5e-4d20-9d20-a5844113284112>
</Objects>
 <!--Comment about something-->
```

Is using regular expressions on input stream the only option here?

Comment: there is nothing special about having a comment node under outside the root element. Just instantiate the XML API and iterate the node ...

Comment: Not really working that way...

Comment: how the code so other can help you delve into it... otherwise, the comment exchange is not an effective use of time

Comment: @vtd-xml-author i have posted my code, and there is not way to access comment outisde xml using xml api

Comment: What xml api are you using?

Comment: I am using Linq to Xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# using LinqToXml you can get comments as follows:

```cs
var xml = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

var comments = xml.DescendantNodes().OfType<XComment>();

foreach (var comment in comments)
    Console.WriteLine(comment.Value);
```

Please note that you must to use `XDocument`.

If you use the `XElement`, it will receive data only from the root element of the document.

If you want to get only comments after the root element, use the following code:

```cs
var comments = xml.Root.NodesAfterSelf().OfType<XComment>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to access the comment node with the following code using xpath /comment(). I was able to print out the comment node successfully. I think any properly behaving xml lib should also do the same thing.

public static void main(String[] args) throws VTDException{

```
    String s = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"+
    "<Objects>"+
      "<GUID-bf2401c0-ef5e-4d20-9d20-a2451a199362>"+
        "<info job=\"SAVE\" person=\"Joe\" /> " + 
        "<info job=\"SAVE\" person=\"Sally\" />   " +   
      "</GUID-bf2401c0-ef5e-4d20-9d20-a2451a199362>"+
      "<GUID-bf2401c0-ef5e-4d20-9d20-a583284112>"+
        "<info job=\"SAVE\" person=\"John\" />  " + 
        "<info job=\"SAVE\" person=\"Julie\" /> " +    
      "</GUID-bf2401c0-ef5e-4d20-9d20-a583284112>"+
    "</Objects>"+
     "<!--Comment about something-->";
    VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
    vg.setDoc(s.getBytes());
    vg.parse(false);
    VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
    AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
    ap.selectXPath("/comment()");

    int i=0;
    while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
        System.out.println("---->"+vn.toString(i));
    }
```